# How to include all files within a folder & its sub folders to functions.php?

Tags: theme-development, filesystem

I try to include multiple php files under one category inside my Wordpress theme and the file/directory structure look like this:

```
-Theme Folder
--Functions_Folder
 ---Folder_1
  ----File1.php
  ----File2.php
 ---Folder_2
  ----File1.php
  ----File2.php
 ---Folder_3
  ----File1.php
  ----File2.php
```

I want to include all those sub functions into my theme function.php and I used this code:

```
foreach(glob(get_template_directory() . "/Functions_Folder/*.php") as $file){
    require $file;
}
```

Its working fine with the *.php files located inside the parent folder --Functions_Folder.

Is there any function can call all the files **only** inside the --Functions_Folder including all the sub folders *.php files?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some recursion on the function:

```
function require_all_files($dir) {
    foreach( glob( "$dir/*" ) as $path ){
        if ( preg_match( '/\.php$/', $path ) ) {
            require_once $path;  // it's a PHP file so just require it
        } elseif ( is_dir( $path ) ) {
            require_all_files( $path );  // it's a subdir, so call the same function for this subdir
        }
    }
}

require_all_files( get_template_directory() . "/Functions_Folder" );
```

Comment: Did this helped?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this did not work with me.